# as much per person

Tags: comparison

Joe: Yeah, yeah it’s good that we have that program, but I hear where you’re, y’know, I hear what you’re saying. I am fed up with it, too. I mean I read that the U.S. spends **twice as much per person** on healthcare **than** any other industrialized nation

1)Is the pattern "as much ... than" common in informal speaking?

2)Does "as much per person" mean "as much money per person.."?

Source: A.J. Hoge, Effortless English, Real English Conversation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"as much ... than" is not correct in either written or informal spoken English. It would have been correct to say:

> ..**more** per person on healthcare than...

or

> ..twice as much per person on healthcare **as**...

Spoken English is not always grammatically correct, and in this case the two correct versions may have got mixed together.

"as much per person" does not always mean "as much [money] per person", for example:

> Americans eat twice as much per person as...

In this context, it clearly relates to food. The verb (**spend**, **eat**) or other context indicates what kind of thing "as much" applies to.

Comment: Agree, but I note the quote is either transcribed or simulated spoken text. Since you can't "go back and edit" speech, this kind of "mistake" is common, and there is no difficulty in understanding.

Comment: @JamesK: thanks for pointing that out: I didn't read the question carefully enough. I have updated my answer.